# Multiple queries in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following user model,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Base):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
```

and room model,

```
class Room(Base):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I want to check if there exists a room which has both a and b as members. I tried this,

```
PrivateRoom.objects.filter(members__id=first.id, members__id=second.id).exists()
```

This gives me an error `keyword argument repeated`.
Can someone help me with the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split this over two `.filter(..)` calls:

```
PrivateRoom.objects.filter(members__id=first.id).filter(members__id=second.id).exists()
```

Not only because you can not used the *same* named argument in a Python function call, but if this is possible (it is with `Q` objects), it would mean you are looking for a single member with `id` both being equal to `first.id` and `second.id`.

This is not what you want: you want two different JOINs: one for the first member, and one for the second.